# Select from JSON, use radio input in Vue.js

Tags: json, vue.js, radio-button

I have **props: ['attributes']**

```
    {
    "name": "Color",
    "variant": [
      {
        "name": "Red"
      },
      {
        "name": "Green"
      },
      {
        "name": "Blue"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Size",
    "variant": [
      {
        "name": "L"
      },
      {
        "name": "XL"
      },
      {
        "name": "XXL"
      }
    ]
  }
```

In Template:

```
<div class="form-group" v-for="(attribute, index) in attributes">
    {{attribute.name}}
        <div v-for="(variant, vindex) in attribute.variant">
              <input type="radio"
                   :value="[{name: attribute.name, variant:variant.name}]"
                   :id="'radio' + vindex"
                   :name="'group' + index">
                   {{variant.name}}
        </div>
</div>
```

Result: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZ99U.jpg)

Question: How do I return selected radio buttons in an array? For example:

```
  [{
    "name": "Color",
    "variant": 
      {
        "name": "Blue"
      }
  },
  {
    "name": "Size",
    "variant":
      {
        "name": "XL"
      }
  }]
```

The radio button does not add to the array as a checkbox.

Comment: where is your click handler?

Comment: Click handler only add in array           **  selectVariants: function(vindex) {
                var input = document.getElementById('radio' + vindex);
                this.attr.push(input.value);
            }**

Comment: you need @click handler to bind the radio value to your data

Comment: You can help me?. A simple handler:if cheked - add in array, else delete in array. The problem is that you need to add and delete an object.

Comment: Its easy you can do it yourselg. Just check the vue intro for click events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.

You need to `splice` existing item each time so new value added.

> Main part was searching item and removing and you can do it by looping through current items and find index of existing item and remove it so new value can be updated.

check below code.

```js
var attributes = [{
    "name": "Color",
    "variant": [
      {
        "name": "Red"
      },
      {
        "name": "Green"
      },
      {
        "name": "Blue"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Size",
    "variant": [
      {
        "name": "L"
      },
      {
        "name": "XL"
      },
      {
        "name": "XXL"
      }
    ]
}];

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    attributes: attributes,
    selectedData:[]
  },
  methods:{
     setValue( name, value) {
      //console.log(name,value);
      
      var self = this;
      this.selectedData.forEach(function(val, index){
      
         if(val['name'] == name) {
           self.selectedData.splice(index, 1);
           return false;
         }
      });
      
      
      this.selectedData.push({
        "name": name,
        "variant": 
          {
            "name": value
          }
      });   
     }
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script> console.info = function(){} </script>
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>.half{width:50%;float:left;}</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="half">
     
        <div class="form-group" v-for="(attribute, index) in attributes">
    {{attribute.name}}
           <div v-for="(variant, vindex) in attribute.variant">
                <label>
                <input @click="setValue(attribute.name, variant.name)" type="radio"
                   :value="[{name: attribute.name, variant:variant.name}]"
                   :id="'radio' + vindex"
                   :name="'group' + index">
                   {{variant.name}}</label>
            </div>  
           </div>          
      </div>
          <div class="half">
      <pre>{{ selectedData }}</pre></div>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.